# Should I use a comma before "who" in this sentence, or can it be written without that comma?

Tags: punctuation, commas, subordinate-clauses

Which of the following is correctly written as far as its comma (or lack of comma) is concerned?

1. People who love their jobs can easily excel in their fields of work than those, who put salary on the first place.
2. People who love their jobs can easily excel in their fields of work than those who put salary on the first place.

I have read that we should only put comma before *who* when it adds extra information, but here I think *who* begins an essential part of sentence necessary for fully understanding it.

Comment: Why are you using the comparative *than* construct without using the comparative degree anywhere?

Comment: You can't put a comma before the second *who* in this sentence for the exact same reason you didn't put a comma before the first *who* in this sentence. That said, either sentence is ungrammatical to begin with because of the "easily than". It needs to be either "easier than" or "more easily than". But you can't just say "easily than". That is not English.

Comment: To elaborate, you're looking at two identical constructions. "People who love dogs" and "people who love cats". The only rule that could possibly allow you to use a comma only in the latter would need to be "use a comma when you see *cats*, don't use a comma otherwise". Any other rule — *any* other rule — would give you identical results for both. Consequently, you can only ask if you should use *two* commas or *none*. Using exactly *one* comma is plain impossible no matter what logic you apply. I would vote to close this question on those grounds alone. It is self-contradictory.

Comment: Your first example is commatose.  (But both examples need more.)

Comment: Yes, "easier excel" should be used, but as to your question, no comma should precede "who put salary on" ("on" is questionable too. Perhaps just "who put salary first." Either way, it's a restrictive relative clause and shouldn't take a comma. FUHL

Answer (score 1):

The most literal translation of your example which has valid syntax and semantics and is reasonably idiomatic would be something like:

> People who love their jobs can *more* easily excel in their fields of
>   work than those who put *salary first*.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. "...who put salary first" is a necessary part of the description of "those" and so *must* be written without commas. The first version is incorrect.

Both sentences contain additional errors. There must be a comparative word such as "more" if the word "than" is to be used - and "in first place" is the correct way to use that phrase.

Answer (score -1):

'People, who love their jobs...' says that all people love their jobs. 'People who love their jobs...' talks about only about those people who actually love their jobs. I suspect you want the second meaning, but as others have said, you also need the 'more than' construction - you don't get it just from 'excel.'